# Json.net seems to rely on $type being the first property. Is there a way to lift that restriction or to easily reorder my json?

Tags: serialization, json.net

I'm building polymorphic serialized types in JavaScript and deserializing them in .Net. This works fine, unless my "$type" property is not the first property (Json.net seems to ignore it then).

So:

```
{
  "$type" : "...",
  "FirstName" : "Bob"
}
```

works (it deserializes to the type provided by $type), but:

```
{
  "FirstName" : "Bob",
  "$type" : "..."
}
```

doesn't.

Is there a way that I can make the order not matter, or an easy way to take my json string and modify it such that my "$type" properties are always at the top, in .Net? In other words, can I use json.net before I deserialize the string to re-order the properties so that "$type" is on top? I don't want to make it a requirement on the JavaScript/serialization side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: Use `MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead`

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm

---

It has to be first.

You could load the JSON into a JObject, rearrange the property order so $type is the first property and then deserialize that.

Comment: That worked, but why is the order requirement there? Can't you just scan all of the properties looking for one named "$type", rather than just looking at the first? That way we don't have to jump through the re-ordering hoop when deserializing. And thank you for this great library. It really is the best.

Comment: Because the properties are never loaded into memory all at once. Type has to be first so the object is created as the correct type and then additional property values are populated onto it.

Comment: I wish you would give a serialization configuration to adjust loading in memory all at once to handle this. Because relying on the order of attributes  doesn't seem to be a wise solution.

Comment: It looks like I found the related config: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm